# iPhone 5 cannot see campus network

Tags: ios, network, wifi, iphone

I have an iPhone 5, which works great at coffee shops, home, work etc.. but when I am on campus it cannot find the wireless network. There is not even a listing for the network, or the guest network that also exists. But, anywhere else it works fine.  I tried resetting the device, but the behaviour persists.

What could be wrong? Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Is it at all possible that the campus network does not broadcast it's SSID?

Try this, go into Settings -> Wi-Fi and tap on "Other..."

Type in the name of the campus WiFi network and its password.

Will that allow you to connect?

Comment: there is no password, it uses mac address to assign hosts, but i can try manually entering the network ID.

Comment: Then the IP address has to be registered with the campus IT department. Either automatically or manually. if it's the latter a call to the help desk might be in order...

Comment: it is registered, our IT dept assigns automatically based on mac address.

Answer (score 0):

- Get [Airport Utility](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airport-utility/id427276530?mt=8)
- Open Settings App and turn on Wi-Fi Scanner for that app
- Open Airport Utility
- Tap Wi-Fi Scan
- Optionally enter the network name if you care only for that SSID

After getting a minute or two of scans, you can inspect the RSSI to make sure the network is viable from a reception point.

If that's good, then you need to get help from the admin on that network to know why a specific base station isn't letting your iPhone on. Alternatively, you could open a support ticket with Apple and see about getting the raw logs from the iPhone. You'll likely have to pay for that option either by being an enterprise account, have apple certifications or pay per incident, so you'll likely want to make sure the campus resources can't help you out before going to Apple.

Comment: yeah, I took it to Our campus IT dept, and they cant figure it out.

Comment: @j0h Cool. The RSSI information will be helpful. Feel free to post a new question with those details if you need more help. Also, list the hardware the campus uses (meraki, aerohive, other...) and whether they use any custom settings. Most campus have a web article on how to connect, so linking to that will help us help you.